# Custom Form Password Authenticator return only UserInterface symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Symfony implement - Custom Form Password Authenticator
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_password_authenticator.html

So this part of code get my user provider class defined in services.yml via `UserProviderInterface` and return `UserInterface`.

```
public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
{
    try {
        $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($token->getUsername());
```

By default my custom user class provider implement `AdvancedUserInterface` with some more functions: http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/AdvancedUserInterface.html

```
class Users implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
```

Question: How to implement `AdvancedUserInterface` with `UserProviderInterface`. Or I simply need to recreate this `AdvancedUserInterface` functions manually and check manually after loaded user object?

Thanks. I hope you understand.

**EDITED:**
It look like AdvancedUser Interface functions not called in custom password authentication automaticaly.
So after get user object need to call manual this functions

```
   try {
        $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($token->getUsername());
        if ($user->isAccountNonExpired()){ throw new AuthenticationException('expired');}
        if ($user->isAccountNonLocked()){ throw new AuthenticationException('locked');}
        if ($user->isCredentialsNonExpired()){ throw new AuthenticationException('credExpired');}
        if (!$user->isEnabled()){ throw new AuthenticationException('disabled');}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably have something confused.

The `AdvancedUserInterface` - indicate user instance, and extends from `UserInterface`.

The `UserProviderInterface` - indicate of providers for loads users (`UserInterface`).

In method `loadUserByUsername` you can returns `AdvancedUserInterface` instances.

As example:

**User:**

```
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface
{
  // .. Some fields and functions
}
```

**User Provider:**

```
class MyUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
  public function loadUserByUsername($username)
  {
     // Get the User instance from DB or another system
     return $user;
  }

  // Some functions
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't explain what i want to get. I did't understand why advanced user interface functions not called.. with custom UserProviderInterface or without, special functions are in $user object, but not anywhere called.